# Migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 in new domain but users reside in old domain

Tags: 2013, 2010, migration, user-accounts, migrate

We need to migrate a site from SharePoint 2010 in Domain A to SharePoint 2013 in Domain B. Domain B has a trust to Domain A and it is planned to keep the users in Domain A - they won't get migrated to the new environment.

Normally when we do migrations where there is a domain change we have to migrate the users (Move-SPUser) but in this case (where we don't move the AD accounts) I don't know if this is necessary. Well surely we have to setup new service and app pool accounts for the site to run on the new server but do any of you know if there may be a chance that even as we don't migrate the users if we have to change them somehow?

The users will be used to log on to the SharePoint in Domain B and there is data in the site that uses these users and those links should be kept intact.

Btw: SP2010 uses classic authentication and in SP2013 we will be using claims authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on the same exact environment and based on my experience there is no need to migrate the users. but i would like to highlight some key points/topics that you need to take care of.

1. you need add trust b/w the two domains on the target site collection specific to people picker to search across different forests/domains. pls refer the below link : [Reference Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg602075.aspx)
2. Adding users from the old domain (if required in future) will be slower and litter bit frustrating as it takes time to complete the trust validation and so on.
3. its obvious that user migrating from classic to claims needs to be done and i hope you are aware of those powershell scripts which are available in msdn articles.
4. **Service accounts/App pool accounts must be changed to the domain accounts of the newer domain. The main reason is that the sites will continue to work even if you dont change them but the response time will be exteremly slow and also there will be frequent downtime or complete distruptions of the entire farm or web applications because of latency b/w domain controllers and due to various trust related issues.so, it is highly advises to make sure that the service accounts should be the domain accounts of the in-house domain.**
5. Overall the response time for new domain or in-house users will be way better than the other domain users.